# Jpanel Move items freely at design time

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, jpanel

I am very new to Java Swing programming and I have a small problem.

When I design a user interface using Jframe and JPanels, JPanel does not allow to drag and drop an item in a place I desire (At design time ). Lets say I add a button to JPanel, then the button is stuck in the middle of the panel and I cannot drag it to a place I desire.This does not happen when I add items directly to the JFrame.

I tried using `setBounds(int x, int y, int width, int height)` method to move the button in JPanel but it did not work.Following image would describe my problem well. I want to drag the button in the JPanel to the left, just like the button added in the JFrame.

Button in JPanel - Top and JFrame - Bottom:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nwq4i.png]

Is there a way to drag and drop items freely in the JPanel as well?

Thanks.

Comment: Don't use an IDE to generate your GUI code. Instead code the GUI manually so you can be in full control of the panel and the layout manager used by each panel. For example by default a JPanel uses a FlowLayout with components centered. If you want the button on the left then change the layout manager to use FlowLayout with components left aligned. IDE's are a good tool to help you compile, debug etc., but the code generated will not be portable if you ever use a different IDE.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @camickr . I understand your point. My problem is, even if I manually code it, wouldn't Jpanels use "FlowLayout with components centered" as you have mentioned making my work redundant? If it is not the case I can give it a try to design GUI manually.

Comment: I already stated you can change the layout manager to use a FlowLayout with left alignment. Read the FlowLayout API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting as an answer since I do not have enough reputation to comment. I see you are using eclipse for building your GUI. However, Netbeans IDE allows you to design the interface as you have mentioned.

While creating the GUI manually is a good idea, if you want to speed up the process, you would need to use an IDE.If you are not restricted to Eclipse and want to use an IDE, I would suggest Netbeans.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. Also Eclipse has its [WindowBulder Editor](https://www.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/)  Gui designer, so there is no need to switch IDE just for that.

Comment: *"since I do not have enough reputation to comment"* Trying to circumvent the established rules of use of SO will attract down-votes, which will in turn delay the time you can post comments. Don't try to game the system. It is set up this way for good reason.

Comment: Thank you for the reply but I intend to manually create the GUIs.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the properties of the Jframe or JPanel, there is a property as Layout, select the 'Abosolute Layout' from them. Then you can place any AWT Component you desire.